# Meaning of "втрескался"

Tags: word

I am having problems with the word
"втрескался", the context being -

> Сказ о том как Ванька дурачок  втрескался в распрекрасную заморскую
>   принцессу с грустными очами, и как полез ее спасать.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian SE! To make this question on-topic some prior research effort supposed to be clearly indicated - like what versions you have on your mind so far and why you still not satisfied with them.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most exact translation would be, amusingly, "had a crush on" that princess. That is, sudden romantic feelings.